# Is it right that FindComponent will even find things declared private?

Tags: delphi, private-members

I have a little question (intellectual curiosity), I have noticed that if a control (of a form) is declared as private and create it dinamically, you can access outside the class with FindComponent.

Is it logically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because when the control is created, it registers itself into its owners list of owned components. And hence there are multiple references to the control.

The reference to the control in the form's class is indeed private. But the reference to the control that the form holds in its Components list is public.

Logically this is very similar to exposing the private variable through a property:

```
property MyPublicProp: TMyControl read FMyPrivateField;
```

Although you don't directly expose the private field like this, the control does so indirectly by registering with the owning form.

Comment: Ok, I know that, but for a logically merely question is it correct that a private object is accessible publically? (mine question is theoretically question)

Comment: I don't really understand your question in that comment. I've explained that there are multiple references to the control.

Comment: So, when I create a control and assign a parent, is like register it and then pubblicate to be accessible for every one...

Comment: Yes, that's it. Actions like setting Parent and Owner leak the object reference to a higher visibility. Class helpers have that effect too. It's not enough just for the form's reference to be private, but the form must keep the secret too. It's like the form put the object reference is a safe but then told everyone what the passkey is.

Answer (score 4):

FindComponent returns components based on their owner and name. It doesn't use the private variable, as you can see by trying to use FindComponent without any class member variable at all (use a local variable instead): it will continue to work.

The keyword `private` only means that you cannot refer to that name. If other ways to refer to the underlying control are provided, the keyword does nothing to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Is it logical? Well, the private variable is not accessible in code outside this unit, and is not accessible in code outside this class when you use `strict private`. That is all what private  visibility means.

Sure you can circumvent that by using `FindComponent` or stepping through the `Components` property, which could be prevented by not assigning an owner. (Note: when you do set a parent, then no owner is required for auto-destruction). But then you can circumvent thát by stepping through the `Controls` property of the parent. And even when the private variable is not a control, but say an integer instead, you can access that variable by means of *hacks*, though in such case you would have to know the signature/declaration of the class type.

To answer you question in depth, one should know why the visibility indicators are made and how their usage was intended. I suppose they were not designed for keeping variables safe from theft protection, but merely as purpose for programmers to be able to do administrative internal tasks within classes and to impose certain handling for users of those classes. No program nor component will ever become hack-free.